# McEliece parameter tuple (n, k, t) through BouncyCastles (m, t, poly)

Tags: key-generation, mceliece

I am using BouncyCastles Java API and want to use McEliece encryption. After browsing through various paper for finding good parameters (e.g. [How to choose McEliece's parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26718/how-to-choose-mcelieces-parameters)) I am now having the problem, that I do not see a possibility to set these parameters with the BouncyCastle API.

In all papers, the parameter set is a 3-tuple: *(n, k, t)*. But with BouncyCastle, I can only specify the 3-tuple *(m, t, poly)* for keypair generation.

**How do they correspond to the *(n, k, t)* parameter set?**

Comment: It's super annoying that this question was closed. I know it's "technically" a programming question, but it still would have been helpful to learn the answer, and— let's be honest —this question is kinda out-of scope for Stack Overflow since it's not *really* a question about *programming*.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are specified in the parameters object. You give them normally in the constructor: `new McElieceCCA2Parameters(m, t, poly)`. I am however not sure how they map to the canonical parameters of the crypto system.

Javadoc: http://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/mceliece/McElieceCCA2Parameters.html

Comment: I know that I can specify these parameters, but how do they correspond to *(n, k, t)*? And which level of security do the default values provide? Is there a way to define *(m, t, poly)* so that *(n, k, t) = (6624,5129,118)*?